# What is the property name to break long lines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have long text line I would like to show it next line.
[image]

What is the property name in VS Code?

Comment: More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122175/automatically-hard-wrap-lines-at-column-in-vscode/45883430

Comment: Alt + z worked great. Wanted to see commit details of a line, but VS Code cuts it with "...". With Alt+z it provides multiple lines and I could see the line's commit details.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The menu under `File > Preferences` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>  (on Mac `Code > Preferences > Settings` or press <kbd>Command (or Cmd) ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) provides entries to configure user and workspace settings. You are provided with a list of default Settings.

Set `editor.wordWrap: on` in your `User Settings` or `Workspace Settings` under preference.

Select the below options to change to the desired settings.

- `Off` - Lines will never wrap.
- `on`  - Lines will wrap at the viewport width.
- `wordWrapColumn` - Lines will wrap at "Editor: Word Wrap Column".
- `bounded` - Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport and "Editor: Word Wrap Column".

You can toggle word wrap for the VS Code session with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (macOS: <kbd>Option (or Alt) ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) or select `View >  Word Wrap` from Menu.

For more about [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace) or [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Comment: `"editor.wordWrap": "bounded"`, as the documentation suggests.

Comment: Now it's on and off no more true and false ;)

Comment: don't forget the "Wrap Line Length" for HTML in settings

Comment: This is not exactly achieving what I want. This wraps the same line into multiple. It's still the same line. I want the formatter to break it into multiple lines if it passes a specified column length

Comment: @Antonio Try SHIFT-ALT-F to format your file.

Answer (score 94):

On Windows, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (macOS: <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) to toggle word wrapping, or, select `View` > `Toggle Word Wrap` from VSCode Menu.

Answer (score 35):

For Windows, Pressing Alt+Z will break the line.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows users do the following in -->

1. Open VScode
2. Go to Settings(Gear icon on the bottom-left side)
3. Click Settings in the menu
4. In the searching bar search for "word wrap"
5. Click the drop-down menu and change it to "on"

This setting will wrap your words according to your editor: viewport.

In case this auto wrapping isn't working you can press -->  Alt + z to wrap content

Answer (score 3):

In *VS Code*:

1. Install [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) plugin. (or any Formatter)
2. Go to the file & select the desired part.
3. Right-Click on it & select `Format Selection` Or press <kbd>Ctrl + k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

***HTML > Format: Wrap Line Length***
set the maximum number of characters (for example - 1000)

Answer (score -1):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to toggle word wrapping or select Main menu "Edit>Advanced>Word Wrap" .