# Show line ends in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a very simple question, how can i display the end of a very long line in vscode ? I did not succeed of displayng it

Here is the screenshot that will be more explicit :

[image]

At the end of the line we can see 3 dots there is more code after that, how can i display everything ?

Thanks in advance to the community !

Comment: In the bottom-right corner of the window, there is an indicator that says "CLRF" or "LF" which will let you set the line endings for a particular file. Clicking on the text will allow you to change the line endings as well. Hope to help, my friend.

Comment: @Tomato32 I tried either LF or CRLF and the end of the line still does not show :(

Comment: Try installing this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sohamkamani.code-eol

Comment: @Tomato32 It works !! put the answer as the real one and i will choose it as the answer :) Thaaanks !

Comment: Yeah. Thank you, my friend :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: How to show line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525417/visual-studio-code-how-to-show-line-endings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing this extension. Hope to help, my friend :))

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sohamkamani.code-eol

Answer (score 1):

on MacOS, `Preference -> Settings -> Editor:Word Wrap`  choose any option but `off`.

refer to: [What is the property name to break long lines in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40781973)