# How to break long statements into multiple lines on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to break up long lines of code for better readability, but every time I save the file, VS Code reformats it back into a single line. I want to retain auto-formatting of code because it makes indentation easy, but this inability to break it up into multiple lines is really beginning to bother me.

I toggled with `wrapAttributes` and the `html.format.wrapLineLength` settings to no avail.

How do I preserve/automatically break-up long lines of code?

PS: I use the Prettier extension, but could not identify any setting there that helped with this either.

Comment: You should use Prettier in your project. And let him formatting your code.

Comment: I already use Prettier

Answer (score 1):

## In the vscode settings there is the automatic line break option

Add the following to your `settings.json` file

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
```

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PBUf.png)

Answer (score 0):

there is a similar question: [What is the property name to break long lines in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781973/what-is-the-property-name-to-break-long-lines-in-vs-code/40782188#40782188)

1. Opening the settings.

   - For windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
   - For Mac, press <kbd>Command (or Cmd) ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
   - Or click the gear icon on the bottom-left side
2. Search for "word wrap".
3. Set `Editor: Word Wrap` **on**.