# Q: How to brake one long line of code in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I was watching a video tutorial and realized that the guy can copy/paste the code in **Sublime text** editor and getting it all on screen and not in the same line, even when his screen is splited:

Example image of the tutorial guy in Sublime
[image: Example image of the tutorial guy in Sublime]

Example image of what i get in Vs Code
[image: Example image of what i get in Vs Code]

So i wanted to know if that is possible on **Vs Code** Studio. I looked a lot around and found nothing, so i'll be happy if you can tell me.

Edit: Thanks to Mateusz now i know that i didn't found what i was looking because i didn't know that this is called word wrapping or line breaking. Thank you! Already edited the title in case more people look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called word wrapping or line breaking.

Select "View > Toggle Word Wrap" from VSCode Menu

edit: Here is a similar question: [What is the property name to break long lines in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781973/what-is-the-property-name-to-break-long-lines-in-vs-code/45845731)

Comment: Also found thank of you that you can do it with **ALT + Z** if you are on windows.