# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, string

In my application, I wrote a custom component to display the header and subheader for each page. See code below:

```
      <H 
        header = "Header" 
        subheader = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
      />
```

**Problem:** I want to split the string across multiple lines, so I added a backslash \ as suggested to do in this source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal.

However, when the page is rendered the **\ is included in the subheader text**.

How can I have multiple line string with the correct text displaying?

Note: I also tried in **single vs double quotes** and tried using the `+`operator.

**Update**: I got it to work by adding `` between the text and by placing {} around everything.

Comment: Read the part about not putting any spaces/indents after the \.  A more modern solution might be to enclose the text in backticks `\`\``

Comment: Check out these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229792/adding-a-new-line-in-a-jsx-string-inside-a-paragraph-react). They are kinda similar. Hope it helps =D

Comment: @ThamyBessa I want the text to appear in a single line, but I want the string in the IDE to be split into multiple lines

Comment: @James I did not have any spaces/indents after the \. There are no errors reported, but the \ is still present. I even copied and pasted their string from the website, and the \ are still present.

Comment: @user19251203 which IDE are you using?

Comment: VS code @ThamyBessa

Comment: It looks like you have `...elit, \<newline><indent>sed...`  It might not be relevant.

Comment: @james I am not sure what the signifies, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using backticks?

Comment: @James i also tried the backtick example like the one in the site. I also tried backtick with the \, just in case. Both have errors.

Comment: @user19251203 So you just want the lines wrapped in your VS code not actually on the displayed component right? If so, I think you can configure your VS code for it like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781973/what-is-the-property-name-to-break-long-lines-in-vs-code). Hope it helps =D